# can the web.config file be removed while the application is running?

Tags: asp.net, iis

If the web.config file is removed while the asp.net application is running, will it still continue or will it not allow config file to delete?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the `web.config` file?

Comment: @Izzy Just a question I was asked by the interviewer... basically web.config, unlike any other file, can be deleted..

Comment: Yes the web.config could be removed you can test it. The Website will give you error once you have removed it.

Comment: A change like that will trigger app domain reload for ASP.NET apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default .NET monitors a few of the standard files/directories such as ~/web.config and ~/App_Code/. Once a change has been made, the application pool is reset. When the application pool starts back up, if there is no web.config file, the application will immediately crash.